# suppress print() function in python modules

Tags: python, python-module

I'm building a multi module python program

in each module i have some function where i used to print some output during debugging of each individual module

while calling modules's functions  in the main program body those print function issues output

How I can suppress these print output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use the `Logging` class (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) provided by python. By using `logging.debug` instead of `print` for class debug messages, if the logging level in main is above debug (>10), then these debug messages will not be displayed.

Comment: I figure out I can do this by collecting all required std output under a conditioned section in each module using the 

If __name__ = "__main__" :

so it won't run when importing that module in another nodule